Repeated observations for survival analysis
I am doing a survival analysis in Stata looking at one-year mortality outcomes after participation in a jail-based program. I have 350 unique individuals that attempted the program a total of 550 times and I am using a propensity-matched control group. For those who attempted the jail-based program more than once, my initial analysis only included the last program attempt, as I would think that including previous attempts as observations in the model would lead to "survival bias" since, by definition, these individuals would not have experienced the event ("death") to be able to attempt the program again. However, I have received feedback from a reviewer that, by not including all the treatment attempts, this leads to survival bias. This does not make sense to me. Am I making the right decision on the study design to only include the last program attempt? If not, should I account for repeated treatment attempts by just using the vce(cluster) option or should I be doing a multilevel survival model to account for observations nested within individuals? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I suspect that the reviewer sees the following problem with survivorship bias: if you use the last program attempt for all individuals, then you are selecting for individuals who didn't die after any previous attempt. No time for an answer now, but some form of multi-state model seems necessary.

The thing I can't conceptually understand is that including previous program attempts for the individuals that attempted the program more than once will add person-time to the hazards model where the event was not experienced because, by definition, they survived to attempt the program again. Wouldn't this inflate the treatment effect in the model? Most people only attempted the program once, and there were 550 program attempts among 350 unique individuals. I want to put as much information as I can into the model but also don't want to make an incorrect methodological decision.

A proportional hazards model doesn't directly use person-time. At each event time, it simply compares the covariate values of the individual with the event against those of all individuals at risk at that time. As Thomas Lumley notes in his answer, one simple solution is to limit yourself to analyzing the first exposure to the jail-based program; that gets around the survivorship bias. If you want to include information on subsequent exposures, you will need some type of multi-state model that takes within-individual correlations into account.

It's fairly common in this sort of scenario in medical data to analyse only the first event for each person, since they are more comparable (and everyone is guaranteed to be alive at the start of the first time).
Otherwise, you could use some sort of multi-state model as @EdM suggests, or use one of the repeated-event versions of survival analysis. I wouldn't use a multilevel model; I'd use a Cox model with sandwich standard errors.  You'd need to decide whether the time scale was time since the start of the current period (with number/duration of previous periods as covariates) or time since the start of the first period (with left truncation for later periods). Either could be reasonable.
